# JMenu remains selected after a mouse click

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I am having a `JApplet` with a menu bar. The issue is whenever I click on the menu, no matter what the result is, it remains selected unless I click somewhere else on the screen.

Here is a small sample code to depict the scenario:

```
public class Frame extends JApplet{

    public static String title = "Tower Defence Game";
    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu menuCreateMap;

    @Override
    public void init() {

        menubar = new JMenuBar();

        menuCreateMap = new JMenu("Create Map");

        menuCreateMap.addMenuListener(new MenuHandler(new Frame()));  

        menubar.add(menuCreateMap);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getHeight(), getWidth())); 
        setVisible(true);           
    }
}
```

The `MenuHandler` class

```
public class MenuHandler extends Thread implements MenuListener {

    Frame frame;
    JMenu myMenu; 
    MenuHandler menuHandler;

    MenuHandler() {}

    MenuHandler(Frame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;     
        menuHandler = new MenuHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void menuSelected(MenuEvent e) {

        myMenu = (JMenu) e.getSource();

        String selectedOption = myMenu.getText();

        if(selectedOption.equalsIgnoreCase("Create Map")) {

            menuHandler.start();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        label.setText("Hello");
        label.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        this.frame.add(label);
    }   
}
```

This code would throw an exception but you would see that the Menu would stay selected.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Don't use MenuListener, attach an ActionListener to the menu item instead

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a Frame within an Applet, this could cause a SecurityManagerException

Comment: It probably looks like it stays selected **because** of the exception.

Comment: I think you need to take closer look at [How to use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) or consider using a toolbar

Comment: What you are seeing is the expected result, a JMenu is a container for JMenuItens, it itself is not meant to be an actionable item

Comment: @MadProgrammer - As far as I know, MenuListener is implementing ActionListener internally. And Frame is just a class name, its doesn't mean the container.

Comment: @whiskeyspider - So if it stays selected because of the exception, how should bring it back to normal?

Comment: No, it stays selected because that's what it's designed to do. This is not the way it's suppose to be used

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I agree that we should not use it in this way. I am now adding JButton to the menu bar instead of JMenu and I got what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, add a button to a JToolBar, add JMenu to JMenuBar and add JMenuItem to JMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to trigger an event by the JMenu component in the JMenuBar, we should try changing it and adding JBUtton to the JMenuBar instead of JMenu. Because JMenu is not supposed to be used this way. Although, if you have a JMenuItem inside that JMenu, then you can trigger an event and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Or you should use a `JToolBar` to add `JButton`s to as that is the expected user experience, no one expects to find anything other then menu's on a menu bar...